# When using an instanced scene, the light source used in it does not work

Tags: 2d, instance, game-development, light, godot

I have an asteroid scene and a planet scene. When I run the asteroid scene separately, the child lights work, and when I generate them in the planet scene, the glow disappears. Moreover, I checked if this source is in the asteroid when it is already instanced as a variable, but has not yet been added to the scene. At this moment, the asteroid's child light source is absent.Eventually asteroid changes illumination (to no illumination lol) but ofc it shouldn't

[image: Here are scenes design]

Here are ready and process functions:

```
func _ready():
#THERE ARE ONLY MOVEMENT AND COLOR SETTINGS
random_color()
scale = Vector2(0.2, 0.2)
var go = true
rand_generate.randomize()
var delta_speed = rand_generate.randf_range(-0.5, 0.5)
angle_speed = 3 + delta_speed
angle_speed *= speed_scale
life_time = 2 * PI / angle_speed
rand_generate.randomize()
radius = rand_generate.randf_range(min_rad, max_rad)
position = Vector2(0, radius) + rotate_point
radius = Vector2(0, -radius)

func _physics_process(delta):
if PLAY:
    #FUNCTION ONLY FOR DEBUG
    position = get_global_mouse_position()
if not go:
    #CONTROLS SHOULD IT MOVE
    return

#THIS THREE IF'S ARE USED THAT THE ASTEROID
#FIRST SWIM OUT SMOOTHLY, THEN MOVE UNIFORMALLY
#THEN GENTLY REMOVE
if time < life_time * 0.3:
    time += delta
    var count_scale = lerp(0.01, 3, time / life_time)
    scale = Vector2(count_scale,count_scale)
elif time > life_time * 0.7:
    time += delta
    var count_scale = lerp(3, 0.01,time / life_time)
    scale = Vector2(count_scale,count_scale)
else:
    time += delta

if time > life_time:
    queue_free()

#DATS A CIRCULAR MOVEMENT AROUND A PLANET
position = rotate_point + radius.rotated(angle_speed*time + PI)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. In the Light2D settings, I set the Layer Min and Layer Max properties to -1 and 1, respectively. Everything works now